# WP Plugin Development - Conditional CSS on shortcode

Tags: wordpress

I'm currently developing a plugin for wordpress.
My plugin-content gets fired on defined shortcode. I pass a parameter to the shortcode to make some conditionals. I am able to load JS conditionally, but I also need to load CSS conditionally.

Lets say I use the shortcode: **[myshortcode css="dark"]**
I make a database query and inject the wanted css.

Is this somehow possible?
I have read some threads about it. I know it is because the Code fires after head is loaded. I wasn't able to find a solution.

What options do I have?

Thank you!

Comment: use inline css?

Comment: Sorry, no. I want to switch the whole stylesheet ...

Comment: Are you extracting your shortcode attributes (`css="dark"`), and saving them as a variable in the PHP?

Comment: Well ... yes I do. But not as global variable if you mean that.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you are searching for these functions:

- [has_shortcode()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_shortcode)
- [get_shortcode_regex()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_shortcode_regex) - here you can find nice example, which is close to your request

You can check your post, page or custom post type on hook by **add_action ( 'wp', 'yourCustomFunction' )** and test if your **get_post_field ( 'post_content' )** contains specified shortcode and conditionally enqueue CSS file based on specified attribute.

Comment: Thanks, I have read about this. Performance-issues were mentioned. Because my pages contain the shortcode only without anything else it wouldn't be a problem I think. How would you catch the mentioned shortcode-parameter, when using this way???

Answer (score 1):

There is a better way. You can simply `register` your css and scripts with `wp_enqueue_scripts` by `wp_register_style` or `wp_register_script` and then enqueue the registered scripts from your shortcode. You will have opportunity to enqueue scripts based on certain condition there.

Here is a code example.

```
/**
 * Register scripts
 */
function my_plugin_scripts() {
    wp_register_style( 'dark-css', $css_path );
    wp_register_script( 'script-name', $js_path, array(), '1.0.0', true );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_plugin_scripts' );

/**
 * My Shortcode
 */
function my_plugin_shortcode( $atts ) {
    $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
        'css' => 'default'
    ), $atts );

    if ( $atts['css'] == 'dark') {
        wp_enqueue_style('dark-css')
    }

    // do shortcode actions here
}
add_shortcode( 'shortcode-id','my_plugin_shortcode' );
```

Comment: Hmmm ... I think I tried this too. I have read elsewhere about it. I will try again ...

Comment: Well .. I just tried it. It would be a perfect solution, but the CSS gets injected in site-footer, which is not OK!!!???

Comment: I think html5 allows style reference to be added anywhere in DOM.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you could do something like this to load one stylesheet or the other:

```
function aw_shortcode_function($atts) {

    $a = shortcode_atts( array(
        'css' => 'light', // this is the default value
    ), $atts );

    $colorTheme = $a['css'];

    if ($colorTheme == 'dark') {
        // load/enqueue/get/do whatever based on the css="dark" shortcode attribute
    }
}
```

Comment: I think I tried this already. I use this way for the injection of my JS. As far as I remember it is not OK for CSS because it is too late and after head. It probably would get printed in footer, which is not allowed for css.

Comment: CSS can be printed anywhere in the DOM. It will still get picked up by the browser. With that said, `wp_enqueue_style()` will always put the stylesheet in the `<head>`.